# Implementing a c function callback in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, c, swift, callback, swift2

`CFReadStreamSetClient` has a C-function callback (`CFReadStreamClientCallBack`) in it's initializer,

`CFReadStreamClientCallback` looks like this:

```
typealias CFReadStreamClientCallBack = (CFReadStream!,
        CFStreamEventType, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void
```

I have a method that attempts to handle the `CFReadStreamClientCallBack` C-function callback:

```
func callback(stream: CFReadStreamRef,
        eventType: CFStreamEventType,
        inClientInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    }
```

but when i attempt to set the callback in `CFReadStreamCallback` as follows, it doesn't compile.

`CFReadStreamSetClient(stream, registeredEvents, callback, clientContextPtr)`

I know with Swift 2.0 there's a way to use Swift closures with C-Function callbacks but I cant seem to get it to work.  Does anyone know how it can be done in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a closure that does what you do in the function like this:

```
CFReadStreamSetClient(stream, registeredEvents, { readStream, event, data -> Void in 
    // Do stuff here.
}, clientContextPtr)
```

Also note that C function blocks can't have a context so you can't access self, or any other variable from outside the block.
If that doesn't work can you include the compiler error in your question?

Comment: this works, thank you so much. i was wondering if you may know how to handle this one as well? : ``AURenderCallbackStruct(
            inputProc: ,
            inputProcRefCon: &selfPtr
        )``

Comment: I haven't worked with AudioUnit too much but I'm guessing you got selfPtr by using `unsafeAddressOf(self)` and that that bit is working. Other than that you need this: `AURenderCallbackStruct(inputProc: { inRefCon, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, ioData -> OSStatus in
     // TODO: Stuff that returns an OSStatus
 }, inputProcRefCon: &selfPtr)`

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2.0:

Given a function which takes a function pointer and a context:

```
void c_func_with_callback(void *context, void (*callback)(void *context))
```

It's very easy to call it from Swift, but it won't be possible to access the variables of the enclosing class:

```
c_func_with_callback(nil) { context in
    print("Callback in Swift!") // OK
    self.xxx // error
}
```

If you need to access variables outside of the block, it's possible to use the context to store a pointer to the class:

```
class MyClass {
    func hello() {
        print("MyClass.hello()")
    }

    func classMethodAsCallback() {
        let context = unsafeBitCast(self, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self)
        c_func_with_callback(context) { context in
            let caller = unsafeBitCast(context, MyClass.self)
            caller.hello()
        }
    }
}
let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.classMethodAsCallback()
```

It's even possible to use ANY closure as a callback:

```
class MyClass {
    typealias Closure = ()->()

    func anySwiftClosureAsCallback(closure: Closure) {
        var c = closure
        // closure won't fit in a pointer, so take it's address first
        let context = withUnsafePointer(&c) {
                //(ptr: UnsafePointer<Closure>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> in
                ptr in
            return unsafeBitCast(ptr, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self)
        }
        c_func_with_callback(context) { context in
            let ptr = unsafeBitCast(context, UnsafePointer<Closure>.self)
            let closure = ptr.memory // dereference the address
            closure()
        }
    }
}
let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.anySwiftClosureAsCallback {
    print("Swift closure called")
}
```